# Terminal setup when running make from Vim

Tags: makeprg

What exactly is Vim doing when executing the `:make` command?

I was expecting that it just executes the content of the `makeprg` variable just like running `:!make` and additionally collects the output, but apparently the behavior is different. For example the terminal size is set up differently.

For example create a makefile with the following content

```
check:
    echo asdf > foo.txt
    aspell -c foo.txt
```

Then compare the behavior of `:make` and `:!make`.

Is it different for you, too, or is this something strange with my setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`:h :make`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake):

```
The ":make" command executes the command given with the 'makeprg' option.
This is done by passing the command to the shell given with the 'shell'
option.  This works almost like typing
        ":!{makeprg} [arguments] {shellpipe} {errorfile}".

{makeprg} is the string given with the 'makeprg' option.  Any command can be
used, not just "make".  …

[arguments] is anything that is typed after ":make".
{shellpipe} is the 'shellpipe' option.
{errorfile} is the 'makeef' option, with ## replaced to make it unique.
```

So, it's not exactly the same as just `:!make`. Following through, for [`shellpipe`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellpipe%27):

```
                                                'shellpipe' 'sp'
'shellpipe' 'sp'        string  (default ">", "| tee", "|& tee" or "2>&1| tee")
        …
        For Unix the default it "| tee".  The stdout of the compiler is saved
        in a file and echoed to the screen.  If the 'shell' option is "csh" or
        "tcsh" after initializations, the default becomes "|& tee".  If the
        'shell' option is "sh", "ksh", "mksh", "pdksh", "zsh" or "bash" the
        default becomes "2>&1| tee".
```

So, the actual command is more like:

```
:!make 2>&1 | tee bar
```

And, in fact, if you run:

```
aspell -c foo.txt 2>&1 | tee bar
```

You'll get the same behaviour.

So, this is [perfectly normal behaviour](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Perfectly_Normal_Beast).

Comment: nice reference, that trilogy of five books is awesome :)

Comment: That explains the difference between :make and :!make, thanks! With that explanation it was easy to prepend aspell with screen so this behaviour can be avoided since I do not want to include the aspell output in the errorfile anyway. Anyhow it would be interesting why "|& tee" modifies the terminal width (and "| tee" not, by the way...).

Comment: @koalo aspell might be testing if either of stderr or stdin is connected to a TTY and using to get the display size, etc. (`aspell -c foo 2>bar` works fine too). That would be a question for [unix.se], however :)